# Looping through array and changing value with if statement

Tags: php

I have the following array of data from a `DB` and would like to change the `STATUS` value to a string if it matches criteria

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ORDER] => 1321[DATE] => 2015-10-05 [TEXT] => TESTING [OTIME] => 06:03:03 [STATUS] => 3 [CODE] => ABC) [1] => stdClass Object ([ORDER] => 1321[DATE] => 2015-10-05 [TEXT] => TESTING [OTIME] => 06:03:03 [STATUS] => 3 [CODE] => ABC ) )
```

I want to loop through the data and do and do something like below:

```
if (STATUS=3) {
        STATUS ="replace the number with some text";
    }
```

Comment: So, where is your loop?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your output is stored in $results array so now you can iterate over loop and check like this:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($results);$i++){

if($results[$i]->STATUS == "3"){
    $results[$i]->STATUS = "text";
    }
}

?>
```